# jquery validations not working in ie on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below scripts in my header file.The validations are working fine in chrome
    and firefox.But when running on ie,sometimes the validations works and sometimes not
    working.I have checked the developer console in ie.But no error message showing there.
    Please suggests me how it will work in ie.

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/vars.js"></script>
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-
       1.9.1.custom.js</script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.validate.js">
     </script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `">` on

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-
       1.9.1.custom.js</script>
 //-------------------^
```

It should be like

```
... jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"> </script>
```

Comment: have you put doouble qute `"` after `custom.js`?

Comment: yes.But still not working.As i said it is working fine in chrome and firefox.But in ie sometimes working and sometimes not working.i.e it is directly post the form after click on the submitbutton.